# "Hot Word Detection", bur for different applications

Tags: machine-learning

I have been looking in detecting a specific rhythm/pattern within the temporal domain for a time-series signal. For this purpose, how "Wake Up" words work for devices like Alexa have gained my interest!

I have 2 questions with regards to this matter:

1. Is this just, say, training a model (e.g. CNN) on a specific word (I know audio processing is not this simple, I meant it in it's simplest form) and running it continually until a hot word is detected? if so is the name just a formalization and not a different method of implementing a ML model?
2. If this type of model can be used for a time series signal, namely audio, is there any restriction on applying it on a different set of temporal signals? for example, detecting the onset of an earthquake?

Also, I would really appreciate it if someone could reference a good paper to have a read through on this matter, I have looked online but have not been able to find interesting stuff.

Comment: For question 2, yes there would be no reason it couldn't be applied to another temporal signal, it just depends on how easy that signal is to detect.

Comment: Hello. If you have 2 questions, it's better that you split this post into 2 separate posts, one for each question, but make sure to provide enough context/details in each post for us to understand your problem and question.